# Github Action CI should fail when code coverage is not 100%

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration, code-coverage, github-actions

I want to check the code coverage percentage in the Github Action CI on push and pull requests. I'm using Symfony. I've found actions for Javascript but not for PHP or Symfony-based.

I've already created a GitHub action workflow which is as below:

```
name: Running Code Coverage

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Code Coverage
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        php-version: [8.1]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up PHP ${{ matrix.php-version }}
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php-version }}

      - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_SECRET_TOKEN }}
          fail_ci_if_error: true
          files: ./coverage_report.xml
```

But I cannot achieve my end goal using the above as it uploads the code coverage to codecov and there I can see the %age.

My goal is that the CI should fail when the code coverage is below a threshold like 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from the [official docs on threshold](https://docs.codecov.com/docs/commit-status#threshold):

> threshold (number): Allow the coverage to drop by X%, and posting a success status.

Here is an example `codecov.yml` reference from the same docs:

```yaml
coverage:
  status:
    project:
      default:
        # basic
        target: auto
        threshold: 0%
        base: auto 
        flags: 
          - unit
        paths: 
          - "src"
       # advanced settings
        branches: 
          - master
        if_ci_failed: error #success, failure, error, ignore
        informational: false
        only_pulls: false
```